# How to center element using tables without scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center-align

I have table (only table on the page). It has one row and 1 cell in it.

I want to center contents of this cell vertically and horizontally on the page. I am doing this by such html and css.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>keks</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, table, tr, td {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But this approach adds scrollbars (both vertical and horizontal). How to remove scrollbars? If I remove them by `scrollbar: hidden` content of the cell would not be on the center of the page. It would be a bit lower and righter.

Also maybe my approach is not correct and I can achieve this without adding scrollbars and content would be on the middle.

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/0tpL9o7e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are automatically defined margin values of the HTML. The scrollbar appears for this... you need to reset them first.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

table{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>keks</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just set margins to 0 on body element since that's what created your scrollbars.

You can also hide scrolls by setting `overflow:hidden` but that way you might prevent your users to see some content that comes in later.

Inside webkit based browsers you can actually hide scrollbars using `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` while still being able to scroll, just without the bars showing.

```css
html, body, table, tr, td {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>keks</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **overflow:hidden** on **html** element:

```
html {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will hide scrollbars, but content would be a bit righter and lower then center of the page. Your answer answers how to remove scrollbars, but content is not centered :( Here is example with overflow: hidden. https://jsfiddle.net/14wgunoL/. If you make view port very low you would be able to see that content is not centered.